# Java - Fancy Two Dimesional Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am creating a video game were the player can enter and exit rooms. They may also enter rooms within room or sub-rooms. After all of the collision for this I come up with five Rectangle variables/arrays.

```
static Rectangle exitDoor[] = new Rectangle[1];
static Rectangle subExitDoor[] = new Rectangle[1];
static Rectangle roomDoor[] = new Rectangle[1];
static Rectangle roomLadder[] = new Rectangle[1];
static Rectangle roomInnerLadder[] = new Rectangle[1];
```

Each room can have multiple of each within. I would like to put all of these arrays within an array that creates two versions of them. What I mean is that if the final two dimesional array is named "room" than room[0][0] and room[1][0] (The second zero being the exitDoor array) would be two different values.

I have tried doing the below, but all it does is do the same thing as the first set of code.

```
Rectangle[][] roomCat = new Rectangle[][] { exitDoor, subExitDoor, roomDoor, roomLadder, roomInnerLadder };
```

I am not looking for someone to tell me how to make two dimensional arrays, I can al ready do that. I need someone to tell me how to take them to the next step.

Thanks,
Oak

Comment: It doesn't sound like you want arrays *at all*, but rather a `Room` class that contains these `Rectangle`s as `Door`s instead.

Comment: Than what would I do with the arrays in the class?

Comment: It's an entirely different design.  I don't think that the arrays would benefit you; instead, you'd want to create whole new abstractions to represent this. It's preferable to indexing into a two-dimensional array to accomplish pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I didn't understand what you are trying to do with two dimensional arrays. Actually there is nothing special about two dimensional arrays, they are just array of arrays, if you know what I mean.

However if we look back what are you trying to do in the first place. It's not actually very complicated task.

Actually what you're trying to do is a very interesting concept in many areas such as mathematics  and art, which is called self-referencing. You can see self-referencing in the paintings of Escher and in the conans of Bach. Take a look at the class below.

```
class Room {

    Room outerRoom;
    Room innerRoom;

    Room(Room outerRoom, Room innerRoom) {
        this.outerRoom = outerRoom;
        this.innerRoom = innerRoom;
    }

    // goes to outerRoom
    Room exit() {
        return outerRoom;
    }

    // goes to innerRoom
    Room enter() {
        return innerRoom;
    }

}
```

It's an implementation of a room in your game. As you mentioned there might be another room inside the room, therefore there might be another room outside the room. So if we want exit the room we go to outerRoom. What handy about this implementation is the outerRoom is a Room too. Therefore it contains inner and outer rooms as well.

You may think this class as a matryoshka doll however what we actually implemented is a basic linked list. You can look it up on the internet, and you can use it while you're making your game however it seems like you're looking for something more.

You want to have many rooms inside a room. What you're looking for is a tree, my friend. Look at the class below:

```
class Room {

    Room outerRoom;
    Room[] innerRooms;

    // creates a room with n inner rooms 
    Room (Room outerRoom, int n) {
        this.outerRoom = outerRoom;
        this.innerRooms = new Room[0];
    }

    // sets nth room to innerRoom
    void addRoom(int n, Room innerRoom) {
        innerRooms[n] = innerRoom;
    }

    // goes to nth room
    Room getRoom(int n) {
        return innerRooms[n];
    }

}
```

It's another implementation of a room in your game. Instead of having an inner room, we have an array of inner rooms this time. So you can have as many rooms as you want in the room however you can only have one room outside, just like a node of a tree.

So, I recommend you to look up linked lists and trees on the internet to understand the concept of this kind of self-referencing structures.

Also notice that if there isn't any room outside you can make it null, and if you don't want to have any inner rooms you can set the number of inner rooms to 0.

I hope it helps :).